# what is the advantage of including .c files?

Tags: c, coding-style

when I read ucos source files, I find this code in ucos_ii.c

```
#include "os_core.c"
#include "os_mbox.c"
#include "os_mem.c"
#include "os_q.c"
#include "os_sem.c"
#include "os_task.c"
#include "os_time.c"
```

what's the advandage of including .c files?

Comment: as opposed to including .h files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By doing this, they may be allowing the compiler to do more inlining and/or space optimization. uCos is an embedded operating system, so anything that saves space or time is a good thing. (Within reason, of course)

Comment: +1 for giving a potential reason as to why uCos code might do this

Answer (score 2):

It can simplify the building process by requiring a simpler makefile. In this case, 7 less files need to be added to the makefile. However, as projects become large, it quickly becomes unwieldy.

Another downside is any variable which would normally have internal linkage is now available to the other c files.

Answer (score 1):

I hope someone can correct me if I'm wrong, since my episodes of coding in C are far and few in between, but AFAIK, adding a `.c` file like that lets you treat all the functions and whatnot that are defined in that file as if they were coded directly in the file they are included in. That should let you build up a more complex file from simpler, more re-usable parts.

Comment: Everything you say is true, but it's not the normal way of going about things.  Normally one would compile all the .c files separately and then link them together at the end.

Comment: @CarlNorum I thought as much. Thanks for the follow up.

Comment: But we need to be careful not to include the already included c files in the compilation process otherwise we'd get compilation error (duplicate symbols or something).

Answer (score 0):

i think this is used to import the system library function,and when you need to use a method that from system library than it works